# Turn an array into a string

Tags: arrays, perl

Okay, so I have an array that looks like this:

```
@foo = ("a","b","c","d");
```

... and a string stored in a variable as such:

```
my $foo = "e";
```

I want to turn this into a string that looks like this:

```
"e/a;e/b;e/c;e/d"
```

In other words, I'd like to add "$foo/" to the beginning of each array element and turn it into a string separated by semicolons. How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and [join](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html)

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @foo = ("a","b","c","d");
my $foo = "e";
my $s = join ';', map { "$foo/$_" } @foo;
print "$s\n";
```

Output:

```
e/a;e/b;e/c;e/d
```